# data.table bug, causing a segfault in R

Tags: r, data.table

The following code segfaults my `R 2.15.0`, running `data.table 1.8.9`.

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(date = c(1,2,3,4,5), value = c(1,2,3,4,5))

# works as expected
d[-5][, mean(value), by = list(I(as.integer((date+1)/2)))]

# crashes R
d[-5, mean(value), by = list(I(as.integer((date+1)/2)))]
```

And on a related note, the following two commands have very different outputs:

```
d[-5][, value, by = list(I(as.integer((date+1)/2)))]
#    I value
# 1: 1     1
# 2: 1     2
# 3: 2     3
# 4: 2     4

d[-5, value, by = list(I(as.integer((date+1)/2)))]
#    I         value
# 1: 1 2.121996e-314
# 2: 1 2.470328e-323
# 3: 2 3.920509e-316
# 4: 2 2.470328e-323
```

Simpler command crashing my `R` from the comments:

```
d[-5, value, by = date]
```

As Ricardo points out, it's the combination of negative indexing and `by` that creates the problem.

Comment: Also crashes my R-3.0.0 (with the same version of **data.table**) on a Windows XP box.

Comment: Doesn't crash for me, but gives the different result. R-3.0.0. `data.table version 1.8.8`.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with negative indexing. For example: `d[-5, date := 4:1]` gives this: `Warning message`:
In `[.data.table`(d, -5, `:=`(date, 4:1)) :
  Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'date' (3 unused)`

Comment: Maybe @MatthewDowle could weigh in sometime?

Comment: like @Arun, it did *not* crash for me, but did get different results.  I'm on `R 2.15.3, data.table 1.8.8, Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)`

Comment: Have a look at this:   `d[-5, .SD, by=value]; d[-5, .SD];  d[1:4, .SD, by=value]; `.   It looks like it may not be related at all to the complexity of the by argument, but simply its presence along with a negative index.   also:  `d[-3, .SD, by=date]`

Comment: this caused a crash for me:   `d[-3, .SD, .SDcols="value", by=date]`

Comment: Gives a Segmentation Fault for me - you should always be clear when saying 'it crashes', since sometimes people say that when all they get is an error message.

Comment: @Spacedman - you seem to be the first person to think that, but ok, changed :)

Comment: @Spacedman was the first to state it, he definitely wasn't the first to think it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UPDATE: This has been fixed in v1.8.11. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> Crash or incorrect aggregate results with negative indexing in i is fixed, [#2697](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=2697&atid=975).
>   Thanks to Eduard Antonyan (eddi) for reporting. Tests added.

Answer (score 4):

One hypothesis is that the problem is related to the following lines in `[.data.table`:

```
o__ = if (length(o__)) irows[o__]
              else irows
```

`o__` eventually gets passed to the C code (dogroups.C) as `-5` in this case. One could imagine this causing issues with pointer arithmetic leading to segfaults and/or erroneous values.

A potential workaround would be to use `data.table`'s not-join syntax:

```
d[!5, mean(value), by = list(I(as.integer((date+1)/2)))]
```

which passes through some different logic on the way to C:

```
if (notjoin) {
            ... Omitted for brevity ...
            i = irows = if (length(irows)) seq_len(nrow(x))[-irows] else NULL
        }
```

Comment: thanks, for the record, `d[!5, ...]` is a little slower in my tests than `d[-5][, ...]`

Comment: Filed as [#2697](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2697&group_id=240&atid=975).  Thanks @eddi and user1935457.