# segfault from C stack overflow in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the data.table package in R to read a large dataframe (65046 rows, 101959 columns). fread is working for me for smaller dataframes. When I try to read the dataframe of interest, I get the following error:

```
dat <- fread("input_file")
Error: segfault from C stack overflow
```

R session info is below:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_US       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US     LC_MONETARY=en_US    LC_MESSAGES=en_US   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45  plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.3   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2
```

I found this [question reporting a similar bug with version 1.8.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046696/data-table-bug-causing-a-segfault-in-r), but I am running version 1.9.4 so I am not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: Probably fixed in development version. Please try it, and if you still get segfault, please file a bug on the github project page.

Comment: @Arun,Tried it in the development version 1.9.5, still got segfault. I filed it as anew issue on the github project page.

Comment: I am having this error too, has anyone got a solution?